# viewWithTag returning nil inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a UITableViewController with a custom prototype cell. Inside the prototype cell I have 2 labels and an image. These are tagged with 100 for the image, 101 and 102 for the label. I am trying to access that tags inside this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIImageView *albumArtworkImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        albumArtworkImageView.image = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:albumArtworkImageView.frame.size];

        UILabel *albumArtistLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        albumArtistLabel.text = [self getAlbumArtist];

        UILabel *albumInfoLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        albumInfoLabel.text = [self getAlbumInfo];

        return cell;
    } else {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        MPMediaQuery *audiobookQuery = [MPMediaQuery audiobooksQuery];
        MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: audiobookTitle forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [audiobookQuery addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
        NSArray *albumTracks = [audiobookQuery items];

        NSUInteger trackNumber = [[[albumTracks objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)]  valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber] unsignedIntegerValue];

        if (trackNumber) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i. %@", trackNumber, [[[albumTracks objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[[albumTracks objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        }


        if ([self sameArtists]) {

            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

        } else {

            if ([[[albumTracks objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]) {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[albumTracks objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)] representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
            } else {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
            }

        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

heres a look at the storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

The issue I am having is the lines where I look up the view from the tags are returning nil. I have done this type of lookup before and I can't figure out why they are returning nil. Any help would be very appreciated. I'm not even sure of a good way to debug. I am a C# developer trying to learn objective-c/ios programming. Thanks!

Comment: Change to `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101]`. All of your subviews should be in the cell's content view, not directly in the cell.

Comment: I tried that but it's still returning nil. Anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that viewWithTag: is returning nil? Did you confirm that with logging or the debugger?

Comment: I was looking at the value in the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you an alternative. Make a custom class for `UITableViewCell` and declare its views there; then connect each cell's subviews with these properties and access them directly, without calling viewWithTag.

For example, in your custom cell:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *albumArtworkImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *albumArtistLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *albumInfoLabel;
```

and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.albumArtworkImageView.image = [self getAlbumArtworkWithSize:albumArtworkImageView.frame.size];
cell.albumArtistLabel.text = [self getAlbumArtist];
cell.albumInfoLabel.text = [self getAlbumInfo];
```

Remember to set MyCustomCell in your cell in the storyboard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should the properties be IBOutlets? How do I hook them up?

Comment: I have implemented this and realize that when I switch my iPhone to landscape it works, but when I have it in portrait mode it does not work. Any idea why this would happen? Thanks!!

Comment: Were you able to hook them up? Command + click and drag from the Owner (that is the viewController with the yellow icon) to the subview (label, imageView, etc). 
What doesn't work in portrait mode?

Comment: Yeah it's hooked up and working great in landscape mode but nothing is displaying in portrait mode. Not sure exactly what is causing that.

Comment: That's another issue. I think you're working in a brand new project created with Xcode 6 so you see the UIViewController as a square view in the Interface Builder. Don't you?

Comment: Does your UITableView is full screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61947/discussion-between-leandro-and-user1585542).

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to learn how to properly use size classes. Thanks for all of your help!